# at command in ubuntu apache error 'You do not have permission to use at'

Tags: apache, ubuntu, permissions

I am pretty new at php and ubuntu. I have 2 servers set up, one for development and one for staging. On the dev machine I can use the `at` command without a problem, but on staging I get a permissions error. The `at.deny` (and `at.allow`) files are identical, so it must be another permissions issue.

Any clues?

I see that on the staging server I can only use `at` command as **root**. How can I fix this to be able to use the at command as **www-data**? Again... I checked the `at.allow` and `at.deny` files  ... they are not the problem here.

Answer (score 8):

1) Check if you have file `/etc/at.allow`.

If it exists - just add your user in new line.

If not exists - try to find your user in `/etc/at.deny` and remove/comment it.

2) Restart "at" daemon:

```
sudo atd restart
```

3) Check:

```
at -l
```

or

```
sudo -u myuser at -l
```

The error should not be output.